# How to check MyControl (Subclass from NSButton) is focusing or lost focus?

Tags: swift, macos

Im learning Swift for MacOs and I have a problem is: When i create a new subclass name is MyControl from NsButton. I can not "How to know is MyControl is has Focusing or lost focus?" in the cases if click inside or outside MyControl or cases Some control orther has focus? Sorry. my english is not good.

Comment: Do you want to execute some code when the control becomes focused and will loose focus? Or do you want to check if the control is focused?

Comment: I only want to check if control is focused or not

Comment: I'm a little unsure of what you are asking, perhaps posting some code will help clarify your question. You may be able to ask your MyControl instance's owning window what it's first responder is, i.e., `myControl.window.firstResponder`. This will return an NSResponser object, which you can attempt to cast as a `MyControl` to check if it has the focus

Comment: i just find to fix, that is use NSTrackingArea and add into function "updateTrackingAreas" in myControl code